# Parse boolean XML result

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf

I'm currently using a WCF service to call an external API.

I have a method call `Ping()` used to check is the external API is available and ready to be called.

```
[OperationContract]
bool Ping();
```

I get the following result from the external API :

```
<boolean xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">true</boolean>
```

The error is with my `xmlns` element. In fact, this values works fine :

```
<boolean toto=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">true</boolean>
```

I have the following generic deserialization method :

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var reader = new StringReader(response.Content);

        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
```

Why did I get this exception when calling it with a simple type like boolean ?

```
var res = XmlHelper.Deserialize<bool>(client.Execute(request));
```

> {"There is an error in XML document (1, 2)."}
>
> {"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'> was not
>   expected."}

Everything work perfectly with a lot of complex object

Comment: Is that error message copy/pasted? Because there's a mismatch in `"` / `'`

Comment: Seems to be that little text in (1,2) --> `"` causes the problem. See if you could resolve by making `"` consistent. Put it also after `Serialization/"` (note the quotation mark)

Comment: I got an error with this value `xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">` but none with this one `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">`. Do you know a workaround who works ? Using `response.Content.Replace(@"\", "")` doesn't help I still got the exception

Comment: Why deserialize?  Instead parse the string response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work -

```
var xml = new StreamReader("xmlPath");
var t = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Boolean),"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/");
var o = t.Deserialize(xml); // true
```